# Why is json.loads throwing JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Tags: python, json

I have a string like:

```
j = '{"type":"x","key":"A","attributes":{"label":"test","visible":True,"advancedOptions":True},"fees":[{"type":"set","key":"fee","attributes":{"amount":"5","type":"percent","label":"Test","fee":{"value":"7","type":"percent"},"visible":True}}]}'
```

I'm just wondering why this code works:

```
exec('t = ' + j)
print(json.dumps(t, indent=4))
```

but this code doesn't

```
print(json.dumps(json.load(j), indent=4))
```

It doesn't make sense to me that if a string is first converted into a dictionary, you can load it as json, but you can't convert that exact same string into a json directly %\ ...

`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value line 1 column 40 (char 39)`

Has anyone run into anything like this before?

I read somewhere on the internet that it might have something to do with the size of the string, where json loads just can't handle it or something.

Comment: Its most likely the encoding.  if your data won't fit here you can always upload it to a pastebin and share the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not JSON (e.g. `True` is not JSON) but Python.

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead of `json.loads()` on that string to parse it as a Python literal and end up with a dict.

```
>>> import ast
>>> j = '{"type":"x","key":"A","attributes":{"label":"test","visible":True,"advancedOptions":True},"fees":[{"type":"set","key":"fee","attributes":{"amount":"5","type":"percent","label":"Test","fee":{"value":"7","type":"percent"},"visible":True}}]}'
>>> ast.literal_eval(j)
{'type': 'x', 'key': 'A', 'attributes': {'label': 'test', 'visible': True, 'advancedOptions': True}, 'fees': [{'type': 'set', 'key': 'fee', 'attributes': {'amount': '5', 'type': 'percent', 'label': 'Test', 'fee': {'value': '7', 'type': 'percent'}, 'visible': True}}]}
```